# Statistical independence of degree in Erdos-Renyi random graph model

Tags: probability, statistics, graph-theory

Let $d(v)$ denote the degree of the vertex $v$ in the random graph $G$ coming from the Erdos-Renyi model. I would like to calculate $\mathbb{E}[d(v) d(u)]$.

Clearly,
$$\mathbb{E}[d(u)] = \mathbb{E}[d(v)] = p \cdot (|N| - 1),$$
where p is the edge selection probability specified by the model.
But are $d(v)$ and $d(u)$ statistically independent so that
$$\mathbb{E}[d(v) d(u)] = \mathbb{E}[d(v)]\cdot\mathbb{E}[d(u)]?$$

Is it true that we can break this into the following two conditionally independent cases:

if $u,v$ adjacent:
$$\mathbb{E}[d(v)] = \mathbb{E}[d(u)] = (|N| - 2) + 1$$
otherwise:
$$\mathbb{E}[d(v)] = \mathbb{E}[d(u)] = (|N| - 2)$$

Comment: Not independent. Omit the possible edge $(u,v)$, then the edges from $u$ and from $v$ result from independent choices hence their numbers $\delta(u)$ and $\delta(v)$ are independent with mean $p(N-2)$. Thus $$E(d(u)d(v))=E((\mathbf 1_{u\sim v}+\delta(u))(\mathbf 1_{u\sim v}+\delta(v))=p+2p\cdot p(N-2)+p^2(N-2)^2$$ and $$\mathrm{Cov}(d(u),d(v))=p(1-p)\ne0$$ On the other hand, conditionally on $u\sim v$, $d(u)$ and $d(v)$ are independent with common mean $1+p(N-2)$. Likewise,  conditionally on $u\sim v$ not happening, $d(u)$ and $d(v)$ are independent with common mean $p(N-2)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the degrees are not quite independent, the dependence is very slight. Write $d(u) = d'(u) + x$, $d(v) = d'(v) + x$, where $x$ is the indicator variable for the edge $(u,v)$. The variables $d'(u),d'(v),x$ are independent, and so
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\EE}{\mathbb{E}}
\EE[d(u)d(v)] = (\EE[d'(u)] + \EE[x])(\EE[d'(v)] + \EE[x]) + \EE[x^2] - \EE[x]^2 = \EE[d(u)] \EE[d(v)] + p(1-p).
$$

Comment: What do you mean, "the dependence is very slight"? Can you make this more precise?

Comment: You can compute the covariance, for example, and you will find that it's pretty small.

Answer (score 1):

No, they cannot be independent.

To take an extreme example, let $G$ be a graph on only two vertices $u$ and $v$, and thus it has the potential of having only one edge.

The Erdös-Renyi model creates an edge between $u$ and $v$ with probability $1/2$, so that either $d(u)=0$ with probability $1/2$, or $d(u)=1$ with probability $1/2$. The random variable $d(v)$ has the same distribution as $d(u)$, but they are very dependent. We always have that whenever $d(u)=0$, then also $d(v)=0$, and whenever $d(u)=1$, then also $d(v)=1$.

Comment: I think there must be two cases: where $u,v$ are adjacent and are not, but within those two scenarios I believe the degree to be independent of one another. This accounts for your example. Also, Erdös-Renyi is for any $p \in [0,1]$

Comment: @samfr true. $d(u)$ and $d(v)$ are independent, when $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent.

Comment: $d(u)$ is the degree of $u$, which is the total number of vertices adjacent to $u$.

Comment: @HowDoIMath, I think they are also independent when they are adjacent, the expectations are just slightly different than before to take that extra edge into account.